# How to reverse this bitwise AND-XOR encoding algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, cryptography

I have been given an "encoding" algorithm that does bitwise XOR and bitwise AND. Originally it's a C code that operates on integers with bit-shifts, but I have translated it into a simpler pseudocode that uses bit arrays (1-indexed):

*N is a power of 2 strictly greater than 1*.

```
encode(A : Array of N bits) -> B : Array of N bits

// Split the input into two halves.
    Var A1 : Array of N/2 bits := A[1 .. N/2]
    Var A2 : Array of N/2 bits := A[N/2+1 .. N]

// Initialize the result with all bits to zero.
    For k from 1 to N
        B[k] := 0

// Do the work.
    For i from 1 to N/2
        For j from 1 to N/2
            B[i+j] := B[i+j] XOR (A1[i] AND A2[j])

    Return B
```

For illustration, here's a "live" C++ program: http://ideone.com/NBGGPS

---

For example I have unrolled it for N = 8, then B is like this (symbols: & for AND, ^ for XOR):

```
B[1] = 0
B[2] = (A1[1] & A2[1])
B[3] = (A1[1] & A2[2]) ^ (A1[2] & A2[1])
B[4] = (A1[1] & A2[3]) ^ (A1[2] & A2[2]) ^ (A1[3] & A2[1])
B[5] = (A1[1] & A2[4]) ^ (A1[2] & A2[3]) ^ (A1[3] & A2[2]) ^ (A1[4] & A2[1])
B[6] =                   (A1[2] & A2[4]) ^ (A1[3] & A2[3]) ^ (A1[4] & A2[2])
B[7] =                                     (A1[3] & A2[4]) ^ (A1[4] & A2[3])
B[8] =                                                       (A1[4] & A2[4])
```

That resembles a system of N equations with N variables (knowing that for bits `a XOR b = (a + b) mod 2` and `a AND b = (a × b) mod 2 = a × b`):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
b_1 & = & 0             &   &                &   &               &   &               &         \\
b_2 & = & x_1 \cdot x_5 &   &                &   &               &   &               &         \\
b_3 & = & x_1 \cdot x_6 & + & x_2 \cdot x_5  &   &               &   &               & \pmod 2 \\
b_4 & = & x_1 \cdot x_7 & + & x_2 \cdot x_6  & + & x_3 \cdot x_5 &   &               & \pmod 2 \\
b_5 & = & x_1 \cdot x_8 & + & x_2 \cdot x_7  & + & x_3 \cdot x_6 & + & x_4 \cdot x_5 & \pmod 2 \\
b_6 & = &               &   & x_2 \cdot x_8  & + & x_3 \cdot x_7 & + & x_4 \cdot x_6 & \pmod 2 \\
b_7 & = &               &   &                &   & x_3 \cdot x_8 & + & x_4 \cdot x_7 & \pmod 2 \\
b_8 & = &               &   &                &   &               &   & x_4 \cdot x_8 &         \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

---

Some (informal) thoughts:

1. It is kind of "symmetric": you get the same result if you swap the two halves of A.
2. I have seen examples that you can get the same result for several different inputs ("different" not only by symmetry), so it is "lossy".
3. It looks like a "keyless XOR encryption" (well, not sure this one even makes sense...).

---

Now the challenge is to "reverse" it, i.e. to write some decoding algorithm such that *decode( encode(A) ) = A*.

But after bullet 2 above (and also 1) we know that the solution is not unique, so we must rather find one possible solution such that *encode( decode_one( encode(A) ) ) = encode(A)*, or maybe we can find all possible solutions i.e. an algorithm such that *decode_all( encode(A) ) = { X | encode(X) = encode(A) }*.

(Of course "brute force" is not interesting.)

Now I'm just completely stuck on that... For example, if B[2] = 1 then I know that both A<sub>1</sub>[1] and A<sub>2</sub>[1] are 1, but if B[2] = 0 then I can only say that A<sub>1</sub>[1] and A<sub>2</sub>[1] are not both 1 (they could be both 0, or one 0 and the other 1). Then for B[3] the XOR comes in and multiplies the possibilities...

I tried to somehow "combine" several equations from the unrolling but it's not linear.

What would be the way to go?

<sub>(Also feel free to edit the post e.g. to add relevant tags.)</sub>

Comment: If it helps, this is multiplication of polynomials with coefficients mod 2. (Which is also convolution.) Thus the problem is to factor a degree 8 polynomial into two degree 4 polynomials.

Comment: @adamW Thanks for your hint. I have looked up "convolution" on the web but that's Greek to me :'( Also about "degrees 8 and 4", I guess it's for the N=8 example, so it's generally "degrees N and N/2"? Then can you please point me to an online resource that explains the process to factor? (All that looks overly complicated to me, while the encoding algorithm is so simple...) I have also added a link to a C++ program, and a "math" equation system.

Comment: Yes, it is degrees N and N/2 generally speaking. And it is possible to be easy one direction (encoding) while difficult in the other (decoding). I am only able to recognize that it is polynomial multiplication and cannot help further--I wish you luck. If I learn anything more helpful, I will let you know about it.

Comment: If it is "lossy" as you say I would not expect it to have any inverse.

Answer (score 3):

**Encryption:**

What your equation system shows is that the encryption is equivalent to multiplying two polynomials of degree N/2 on GF(2) (algebra of two elements {1,0} where 1+1=0, that is to say + = XOR).

**"Proof":**

Let A1 be an array of the coefficients of A1: $A1[1]\times x^0+A1[2]\times x^1+A1[3]\times x^2+...$

Same goes for A2

Let B be the product polynomial of $B=A1\times A2$

Polynomial multiplication gives you:

$B=(A1[1]\times x^0+A1[2]\times x^1+A1[3]\times x^2+...)\times(A2[1]\times x^0+A2[2]\times x^1+A2[3]\times x^2+...)$

$B=(A1[1]\times A2[1]\times x^0+(A1[2]\times A2[1]+A2[2]\times A1[1])\times x^1+...)$

In general $B[i]=Sum(A1[n]\times A2[l],n+l==i+1)$   (%2 because of GF(2))

You wrote:

$B[5] = (A1[1] & A2[4]) ^ (A1[2] & A2[3]) ^ (A1[3] & A2[2]) ^ (A1[4] & A2[1])$

This is exactly the previous formula for i=4, you have $B[1]=0$ so there's a shift: your $B[5]$ is the coefficient in front of x^3.

**Decryption:**

If the encryption is polynomial multiplication of two polynomials of degree N/2, the decryption is polynomial factorisation into two parts of degree less than N/2. This can be done with the [Berlekamp Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp's_algorithm) or [Cantor–Zassenhaus Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm)

Note these algorithms will work because we are on a finite field GF(2) where the coefficients have finite possible values.

Comment: What is your question? Please make use of [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks for the MathJax link, looks a bit better now. I'm just trying to give a more detailed answer along the lines of adam W's comments because it is the answer to this problem and the question has no accepted answer. If someone wants to post a clearer answer they are welcome to do so.

Comment: sorry, I somehow mistook your post as a possible question and not as an answer